# How to create trustworthy desktop applications that do not conflict with antivirus software

Tags: python, wxpython, pyinstaller, desktop-application, kaspersky

I am new to desktop application development and have recently created an application using `wxPython` that utilizes the microphone for audio streaming. After generating the .exe file using `PyInstaller`, I encountered an issue where antivirus software, including Kaspersky, categorizes my application as a low-restricted item, preventing access to the microphone.

What are the possible strategies to ensure that my desktop application is recognized as trustworthy by antivirus software and can seamlessly access the microphone?

I have already tried the Inno setup for the code signing,but Kaspersky still flags my application as low-restricted.

Any assistance or advice from fellow developers would be greatly appreciated.